# Ubuntu 14.04 spontaneously shutting down, showing power off menu for a second

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, menu, crash

Recently I have had problems with Ubuntu (14.04) spontaneously shutting down for no obvious reason. I use GNOME, and just before it happens it shows me the GNOME power off menu:

[image: Power off menu]

It doesn't however give me 60 seconds to stop it like the message suggests, and shuts down completely in less than 2 seconds with a "click" sound.

When this happens I can be currently using my laptop or it can just be sitting idle with no programs running (except the terminal) acting as a router.

I am dual-booting Windows 10 for gaming purposes and have never had this problem while running windows, so I don't think it is a problem with overheating. Also, when it happens my laptop doesn't feel particularly warm.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem or how I could look into it?